# Finding intersection of two select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find intersection between the following queries in MYSQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM project.backup_table 
where project.backup_table.date <= (SELECT date FROM project.main_inout_table  ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 1) 
    and project.backup_table.date >= (SELECT date FROM project.main_inout_table  ORDER BY date asc LIMIT 1)  

SELECT *
FROM project.backup_table
WHERE concat(empid,date) not IN (SELECT concat(empid,date) FROM project.main_inout_table
```

**The tables are:**

[maintable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdlFK.jpg)

[backuptable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2K42.jpg)

**My atttempt:**

```
SELECT * FROM project.backup_table
where project.backup_table.date <= (SELECT date FROM project.main_inout_table
                                    ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 1) and project.backup_table.date >= (SELECT date FROM project.main_inout_table
                                                                      ORDER BY date asc LIMIT 1)  and exists (SELECT * FROM project.backup_table
                                                                        WHERE concat(empid,date) not IN (SELECT concat(empid,date)
                                                                         FROM project.main_inout_table));
```

**Problem:** the details of tid 4 is present shouldn't it be filter out by second select query ?

Comment: Neat! But we can't help you if you don't tell us what fields you need to intersect. Have you looked into a `JOIN`?

Comment: Simply AND the two WHERE clauses.

Comment: I simply  need to find he intersection of these  queries @JacobH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intersection would be the rows that meet both conditions.  So, just bring the conditions together:

```
SELECT bt.* 
FROM project.backup_table bt
WHERE bt.date <= (SELECT MAX(date) FROM project.main_inout_table mit) AND
      bt.date >= (SELECT MIN(date) FROM project.main_inout_table mit) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM project.main_inout_table mit
                  WHERE mit.empid = bt.empid AND mit.date = bt.date
                 );
```

Note the following changes:

- The tables are given aliases, which are abbreviations for the table names.
- The columns are all qualified with the table aliases.
- The first two subqueries simply use `MIN()` and `MAX()`.  These could be combined into one subquery or join, but this follows your original formulation.
- The last subquery uses `EXISTS` rather than `CONCAT()`.  Actually, this could also use `IN` with tuples (something that MySQL supports, but not all databases).

Comment: i am having problems with the second select of your answer it doesn't seem to work as the second query  of my question

Comment: SELECT * FROM project.backup_table where project.backup_table.date <= (SELECT date FROM project.main_inout_table  ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 1) and project.backup_table.date >= (SELECT date FROM project.main_inout_table   ORDER BY date asc LIMIT 1)  and exists (SELECT * FROM project.backup_table WHERE concat(empid,date) not IN (SELECT concat(empid,date) FROM project.main_inout_table));

Comment: I tried the above query but the intersection part isn't working can u check what is worng with it?

Comment: The word intersection means nothing in SQL as you are using it. Update your post with your expected results and some test data so we can give you an answer. Or try using `INTERSECT` and see what you get for results between the 2 queries.

Comment: i couldn't post the result table due to my reputation @JacobH